# javascript for show and hide html

Tags: javascript

i'm searching for my site something that can show and hide some html after 10 seconds for example.

This feature is exactly for a games site. I want to show ads during 10 seconds, and after this time, load the .SWF file of the game.

During 10 seconds i want to show the window of the ad in the center of the field where later the game will be displayed. It's like a 700x500px window.

One of the problems is that the ad window maybe 300x200px and i want to put it in the center. It's like i want to make a scene of 10 seconds with that ad showing while the game is loading.

If i try any jquery code solution it's not working, maybe because there's no compatibility with my page theme, that's using already jquery, someone told me that javascript was broken and the console was reporting that the 'cycle plugin' was having issues.

So i beg you to tell me a solution in just javascript or something similar, so i don't have any problem with the code.

Sorry for being so novice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to show/hide and you're asking about the timing? If so look at setTimeout(function, milliseconds). If you need more on show/hide explore jQuery for an easier way or comment back and I can add more on the javascript side.

Comment: I would answer, but I wouldn't want to help somebody make intrusive ad windows.

Comment: Intrusive ad windows? Why did you imagine that?

Comment: Don't know why are you so worried about anybody making intrusive ad windows when you are making offensive comments. I also hate intrusive ad windows, but i think that offensive comments are so bad for the net. By the way, i found the solution without your help, i hate people who says "I would answer, but..."

Answer (score 0):

I quick and dirty solution using jQuery.

```
$(function() { 

    var timer = 0;
    var id = 0;
    if (!timer) {
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            DO YOUR THING
        }, 10000); // <- 10000ms = 10s
    }

});
```

I didn't understand if you want to open a new window or if show the ad on some div. But I wouldn't spend much time on a site that open an ad in a new window every 10 seconds.

Comment: I need something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/qyCX9/ But in my web site i'm experiencing problems with the jquery i already have. I want to show ads before a game loads, like 10 seconds. I want to put the ad over the game while is loading. Maybe it's intrusive, but is a feature i'm searching for years and i didn't find nothing good. If i found it intrusive, i'll be the first to forget this idea.Thanks.

Comment: what is wrong with that code you posted? from what i could understand, it is doing what you want. just change to 10 seconds.

Comment: Is not working with my wp theme i'm using, someone told me "it looks like the javascript is broken, the console reports that the 'cycle plugin' is having issues. It appears that your WP Theme is already including jQuery (v1.3.2) remove the extra <script ... src="https://.../ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>". But it didn't work. Later a persona told me the problem was that i needed to include jquery before including script.js (this file contains jquery code which needs to be included after jQuery). But the same, it didn't worked.